# Chunking/streaming and filtering a time-series in DBT Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a daily_user_product_activity table with the following model:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key | number | hash(date, uid, pid) |
| date | date | date of the activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product associated with the activity |
| updated | timestamp | when the record was last updated |

And a user table with the following model:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uid | number | user id |
| signup | date | date the user signed up |
| ... | ... | ... |

I need to build a user_dormancy table that has a 1:1 row correspondence to daily_user_product_activity such that each day a user buys product X, the dormancy table also captures how long it's been since the user last bought any products as well as the last time the user bought product X. Here's the model (this is related to my two previous questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75440978/time-difference-between-events-in-two-different-tables) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020545/snowflake-sql-hierarchical-time-between-events)):

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key | number | hash(date, uid, pid) |
| date | date | date of the spend activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product the user spent on |
| dormancy | int | days since the user's last bought any products |
| product_dormancy | int | days since the user's last bought the same product |
| source_updated | timestamp | when related daily_user_product_activity record was last updated |
| updated | timestamp | when the record was last updated |

When I first built this model it turned out to be very expensive to run, so I did some pre-filtering to keep costs down:

```
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental'
    , unique_key='KEY'
    , cluster_by=['uid', 'date']
    , pre_hook="""
        {% if is_incremental() %}
        set asof_ts=(select max(source_updated) from {{ this }}
        {% endif %}"""
) }}

{%- set run_date = env_var('RUN_DATE', 'NOT SET') %}
{%- set look_back = env_var('LOOK_BACK', '90') %}

with
asof as (
  select
    {% if run_date != 'NOT SET' %}
    to_date('{{run_date}}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as recent
    {% elif is_incremental() %}
    $asof_ts::date as recent
    {% else %}
    {{ exceptions.raise_compiler_error('non-incremental runs must have a run_date set') }}
    {% endif %}
    , recent - '{{look_back}}'::number as limit
    , limit - 1 as beyond
)
, new_rows as (
  select
    src.key
    , src.uid
    , src.pid
    , src.updated as source_updated
    , user.signup
  from daily_user_product_activity as src
  join user using (uid)
  join asof on true
  where src.updated > asof.recent
)
, past_rows as (
  select
  from new_rows as nr
  join daily_user_product_activity as src using (uid)
  join asof on true
  where src.date > asof.limit
)
, prior_spend as (
  select
    (prior.signup < asof.limit) as is_signup_beyond_limit
    , (prior.spend_date is not null) as is_prior_spend
    , iff(is_prior_spend
      , prior.spend_date
      , iff(is_signup_beyond_limit
        , asof.beyond
        , null)
    ) as prior_spend_date
    , prior.*
  from (
    select pr.date as spend_date, nr.*
    from new_rows as nr
    left join past_rows as pr
      on pr.uid = nr.uid and pr.date < nr.date
    qualify 1 = row_number() over (partition by nr.key order by pr.date desc)
  ) as prior
  join asof on true
)
, prior_product_spend as (
  select
    (prior.product_spend_date is not null) as is_prior_product_spend
    , iff(is_prior_product_spend
      , prior.product_spend
      , iff(is_signup_beyond_limit
        , asof.beyond
        , null)
    ) as prior_product_spend_date
    , prior.*
  from (
    select pr.date as product_spend_date, nr.*
    from new_rows as nr
    left join past_rows as pr
      on pr.uid = nr.uid and pr.date < nr.date and pr.pid = nr.pid
    qualify 1 = row_number() over (partition by nr.key order by pr.date desc)
  ) as prior
  join asof on true
)
select
  key
  , date
  , uid
  , pid
  , (date - prior_spend_date) as dormancy
  , (date - prior_product_spend_date) as product_dormancy
  , source_updated
  , current_timestamp as updated
from prior_product_spend
```

However, I got to thinking:
Getting the most recent previous record from a time-series shouldn't be that expensive. I simply have to partition by user and scan backward in time until I find the most recent record or none at all. That shouldn't amount to a huge expensive table scan.

If you look at the logic below, you can see there's only one ambiguous outcome.

```
    (prior.signup < asof.limit) as is_signup_beyond_limit
    , (prior.spend_date is not null) as is_prior_spend
    , iff(is_prior_spend
      , prior.spend_date
      , iff(is_signup_beyond_limit
        , asof.beyond
        , null)
    ) as prior_spend_date
```

When looking at the window of past data, we either find prior activity (and set the date of that prior activity as prior_spend_date) or we look back further than the user's signup date (and set the prior_spend_date to null because there was no prior spending from the user), or we don't find prior spend activity AND we haven't looked back beyond the user's signup date.

In that last case, the code I wrote above simply assumes the user does have some prior spend activity beyond the look-back window and sets the prior_spend_date such that the dormancy will be equal to look_back + 1. If the look_back limit is 90 days, a dormancy of 91 days tells us that the search for previous activity was cut short by the limited look-back window.

I'm much more familiar with programming languages like Python where you can write a while loop so I can easily articulate the answer I'm looking for with that kind of logic. The hard part is translating it to SQL. What I wan't to do is load chunks (or stream? is that a thing?)
of past data at a time based on the set of new_rows I haven't yet found previous activity for. Then look through the chunk of past data and assign dates to new_rows that have previous activity, nulls to new_rows where I've looked beyond the user's signup date and found no previous activity and filter both of those out of new_rows into a CTE containing completed_rows. Then I want to keep loading chunks of older and older past data for the remaining rows in new_rows and filtering out completed rows until new_rows is 'empty' and completed_rows is full. If that makes any sense.

The set of new_rows should shrink dramatically with each new chunk of past data and in the worst case scenario where I have to look way back for a lot of people, that means most of the history is empty for those people, so it's not really scanning a ton of data.

Anyway... How do I do that?

Above and Beyond:
I tried to simplify the actual problem as much as possible, but it turns out that each pid corresponds to a product that belongs to a three-tier hierarchy of products. Each product_family contains one or more product_groups and each product_group contains one or more products, so each pid maps to a product in a product_group in a product_family. My actual task is to make the user_dormancy table include both spend and free interactions (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75440978/time-difference-between-events-in-two-different-tables)) across the platform (all products), products in the same family, products in the same group, and the exact same product (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020545/snowflake-sql-hierarchical-time-between-events)). The model looks something more like this:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key | number | hash(date, uid, pid) |
| date | date | date of the spend activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product associated with the activity |
| dormancy | int | min(paid_dormancy, free_dormancy) |
| paid_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity |
| free_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity |
| family_dormancy | int | min(paid_family_dormancy, free_family_dormancy) |
| paid_family_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity w/ same family as pid |
| free_family_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity w/ same family as pid |
| group_dormancy | int | min(paid_family_dormancy, free_family_dormancy) |
| paid_group_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity w/ same group as pid |
| free_group_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity w/ same group as pid |
| product_dormancy | int | min(paid_product_dormancy, free_product_dormancy) |
| paid_product_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity w/ the same pid |
| free_product_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity w/ the same pid |
| source_updated | timestamp | when related daily_user_product_activity record was last updated |
| updated | timestamp | when the record was last updated |

My current code has lots of duplications of the 'prior_x' CTE logic chained together. It seems like there are probably Snowflake SQL tools (group by rollup?) that could help me simplify things a lot. I can't give out extra credit, but if you help me: your luck stat will increase significantly!

Comment: Please refer to this method of time series / AsOf join for performance at scale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409949/how-to-do-an-as-of-join-in-sql-snowflake

Comment: To simplify:
paid_activity (PA) and free_activity (FA) are both time-series like daily_user_product_activity. The dormancy table is every time a user engages in paid activity, when was the user's previous paid and free activity related to that product (1:1 relationship w/ PA)

I take the new_rows (NR) from PA, union NR, PA, & FA into U, then do a lag for each dormancy metric:

`(u_date - lag(iff(src!='FA',null,u_date)) ignore nulls over (partition by uid, family, group order by u_date)) as free_group_dormancy` 

then I qualify only the rows I need: `qualify src='NR'`

right?

Comment: That seems right. If you have any problems get it working, ask your Sales Engineer to contact me.